# How to named route in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, routes, router

in Express.js, how can I set a route name so that I can later simply call that route name to retrieve the corresponding URL?

```
File app.ts:
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

File api.ts:
router.use('/auth', authRouter);

File auth.ts:
router.get('/login', AuthController.login).as('my route name');
or
app.get('/login', AuthController.login, name='my route name'); 
...

output:
res.send(anyFunction('my route name')) // => /api/auth/login | https://example.com/api/auth/login
```

Any examples or documentation. Thanks

**UPDATE 03/08/2023**

Although I wasn't entirely satisfied with it (my initial intention was to find a fully automated solution like Laravel), I can accept it. I wrote the route.url.ts file based on the suggestions from the **Answers**.

**route.url.ts**

```
function replaceParams(urlReplace: string, params:  { [key: string]: string } = {}): string {
    const queryParams: { [key: string]: string } = { ...params };
    const url: string = urlReplace.replace(/:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\(.+?\))?/g,
        (match, paramName, regexPart) => {
        delete queryParams[paramName];
        const regex = regexPart ? new RegExp(regexPart.slice(1, -1)) : null;
        return params[paramName] && (!regex || regex.test(params[paramName])) ? params[paramName].toString() : ':' + paramName;
    });
    const queryString: string = Object.keys(queryParams)
        .map((key) => key + '=' + queryParams[key])
        .join('&');
    return queryString ? (url.includes('?') ? `${url}&${queryString}` : `${url}?${queryString}`) : url;
}
export default (routeName: string, params:  { [key: string]: string } = {}): string => {
    const appUrl: string = process.env.APP_URL || '';
    switch (routeName) {
        case 'api.a':
            return replaceParams(`${appUrl}/api/a/:user_id`, params);
        case 'api.b':
            return replaceParams(`${appUrl}/api/b/:user_id([a-z0-9]+)`, params);
        case 'api.c':
            return replaceParams(`${appUrl}/api/c/`, params);
        default:
            return '';
    }
};
```

**app.ts**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.json({
        a: routeUrl('api.a', { user_id: 'user12321423432' }),
        b: routeUrl('api.b', { user_id: 'user12321423432' }),
        c: routeUrl('api.c', { user_id: 'user12321423432' })
    });
});
```

**Output**

```
{"a":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/a/user12321423432","b":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/b/user12321423432","c":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/c/?user_id=user12321423432"}
```

I hope I can get something better than that

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) that adds the route name on [locals](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) property of `res`. Something like this -

```ts
const middleware = async (req, res, next) => {
      switch(req.path){
        case "/api/auth/login":
          res.locals["route-name"] = "My Route Name";
          break;
        // Other case statements
      }
next();
}
```

And then in your controller, you could do -

```ts
res.send(myFunction(res.locals["route-name"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create separate route file where import your all controllers.

add code in your `app.ts` (I assume this is your main file)

```
import routes from './routes/routes';

// Register routes
app.use('/', routes);
```

And add your router code like below:
`routes.ts`

```
import { Router } from "express";
let controller = require("../controller/yourController");
let router = Router();
let apiRouter = Router();


apiRouter.get('/download-errorlog', controller.getErrorLogFile);

apiRouter.post('/get-data', controller.getData);

// Define the API endpoint
router.use('/api/v1', apiRouter);
export default routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new function. This function returns you original url of route you want.

```
export default (name) => {
  const mainUrl = "https://example.com"
  switch (name) {
    case "my route name":
      return `${mainUrl}/api/auth/login`;
    .
    .
    .
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

Then, import the funtion to `auth.controller.ts`

```
// auth.controller.ts

res.send(getUrl("my route name")); // => https://example.com/api/auth/login
```